I am trying to build a ROS/moveit catkin workspace and I get the error Could not find a package configuration file provided by "moveit_visual_tools"
I am Trying to build this workspace: https://github.com/jesseweisberg/moveo_ros I have all the sub folders of moveo ros in src but when I try to catkin_make it gives out this error :
-- Could NOT find moveit_visual_tools (missing: moveit_visual_tools_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'moveit_visual_tools'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "moveit_visual_tools" with any of the following names:

    moveit_visual_toolsConfig.cmake
    moveit_visual_tools-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "moveit_visual_tools" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "moveit_visual_tools_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "moveit_visual_tools" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  moveo_moveit/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

also when trying rosdep install -r --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y I get this error:
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
moveo_urdf: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gazebo]
moveo_moveit: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_visual_tools]

I am currently using ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04, I know that it is a little old but I need it to run on a jetson nano and its the only supperted Ubuntu version.
Also I am pretty new to ROS so I don't know exactly how everything

I would proceed by installing the package, which causes the error:
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-moveit-visual-tools


I also had to change to ros kinetic to make it work because the package was build on it. When i used melodic it would give a weird error with something with eigen in the source code when building

@Jakub Ivan's provided solution should solve the problem of missing packages, but I would suggest running rosdep update (as per MoveIt tutorial) as it seems rosdep cannot find the dependency keys (although I am not sure if they are still kept up to date for ROS Melodic). As a side note, the more common way of building ROS Melodic workspaces is with catkin build.
